# "For all" or "for each"

Tags: quantifiers

In mathematical context, or in the context of mathematical logic, is there a difference between:

> This is valid for *each* x.

and

> This is valid for *all* x.

?

If both have the same meaning, which is preferable?

Comment: This is off-topic: it is not about English language and usage, but about the special language used in maths.

Comment: ... and what about *This is valid for every x* ?

Comment: @ColinFine: So the use of English is scientific texts is off-topic?

Comment: You were asking whether in the context of mathematics there was a difference between the phrases. This is not part of English in a technical context, this is part of the special variety of English used in a technical context, which is different.

Comment: It is certainly about language, since these are some of the same quantifiers that occur in all natural languages. Specifically, _for each `X`, for every `X`, for all `X`_ are standard ways to express the universal (∀) quantifier, while _some `X`, (at least) one `X`,_ and _there exist(s) (an) `X`_ are standard ways to espress the existential (∃) quantifier. These two are what McCawley calls "the logicians' favorite quantifiers", though there's lots more quantifiers than that in every natural language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are valid here, as is 'every' as GEdgar mentions.

I would suggest that 'every' and 'all' are slightly more grammatical in this usage.